# Unable to get /hystrix.stream in Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

I have created a microservice with following dependencies of Spring cloud version `Camden.SR2`. Spring Boot 1.4.1. `http://localhost:8080/hystrix.stream` is not responding.

If I make the Spring Cloud version as `Brixton.*`(RELEASE, SR1,...), I get only `ping:` as reply in browser.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=sample-service
server.port = 8080
```

Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Spring Boot 1.5.x `Hystrix.stream` will only show data if there are actually call's being executed that are annotated with `@HystrixCommand`

If you annotate a method it will publish data to the stream when its being used.

More info: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Brixton.SR6/#_circuit_breaker_hystrix_clients

Answer (score 20):

For those who are using spring boot 2 (I am using `2.0.2.RELEASE)`, the `hystrix.stream` endpoint has been moved to `/actuator/hystrix.stream`.

For me this url worked:

```
http://localhost:8082/actuator/hystrix.stream
```

And yes, have this actuator endpoint enabled via following property:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=hystrix.stream
```