# hystrix stream not responding

Tags: hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using spring-cloud-starter-hystrix:1.2.3.RELEASE in a Spring Boot application. I have 1 HystrixCommand, that I can execute successfully. 
After that I called

```
localhost:8080/hystrix.stream
```

however this Request loads forever and doesn't respond. On Google I cannot find anything about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get /hystrix.stream in Spring Cloud](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447916/unable-to-get-hystrix-stream-in-spring-cloud)

Answer (score 3):

This happens if no command has been executed yet and therefor there are no metrics to publish in the stream.

The 'workaround' is to execute a Hystrix command.

This happens in Hystrix 1.5.8 and earlier. The behavior was changed in Hystrix 1.5.9 that was released yesterday. It will now publish a `ping` message if there are no metrics to publish.

This change was made to fix a bug where the stream would not detect closed connections when there were no metrics to publish. See [Hystrix bug 1430](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1430) for more information.

Comment: The fix doesn't work for me. Updated to 1.5.9, same issue

Comment: @StefanoL Are you sure you are now using 1.5.9. The way Spring boot dependencies work, sometimes fixes you on a specific version. That said, I've not had the time yet to apply 1.5.9 to our application, so my answer is currently based purely on the theory of the fix of bug 1430. I'll likely be able to confirm this tomorrow.

Comment: I added certain gradle dependencies, such as 'hystrix-metrics-event-stream', '1.5.9' expecting to overwrite Spring Boots 1.5.8. Debugging the HystrixSampleSseServlet.java confirms me that the new dependency is used -> The while loop in 159 was extended a bit. By the way using the workaround with the DummyCommand doesn't help as well.

Comment: @StefanoL Ok, I'll take a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: @StefanoL I just upgraded our dependencies to 1.5.9 and it does post the pings in the stream as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the `@EnableHystrixDashboard` annotation added to the dashboard application. Then go to `http://{dashboard-application:port}/hystrix.stream`. On this page you will be asked to enter the URL of Hystrix application which is annotated with `@EnableCircuitBreaker` and of which you want to monitor the stream.